# Jetpack Compose: Usage of Offset in PointerScope

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, offset

I'm having issues understanding how exactly **Offset** works in Compose, specifically in the **`PointerScope`** `onTap` callback function to track the exact location where the user tapped on a UI element.

### Use Case

User is presented an image. Whenever the user taps onto the image, a **marker icon** is placed on the tapped location.

### Code

(You can ignore the button here, it does nothing at this point)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

//private var editMode = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {

        val offset = remember {
            mutableStateOf(Offset.Infinite)
        }

        MyLayout(offset.value) {
            offset.value = it
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyLayout(
    offset: Offset,
    saveLastTap: (Offset) -> Unit
) {
    val painter: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape)

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.95f)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Image(
                contentScale = FillBounds,
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onTap = {
                            saveLastTap(it)
                        }
                    )
                }.border(5.dp, Color.Red)
            )
            
            if (offset.isFinite) {
                PlaceMarkerOnImage(offset = offset)
            }
        }
        Button(
            enabled = false,
            onClick = { TODO("Button Impl") },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.05f),
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small
        ) {
            Text(text = "Edit Mode")
        }

    }
}

@Composable
private fun PlaceMarkerOnImage(offset: Offset) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.marker),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.offset(offset.x.dp, offset.y.dp)
    )
}
}
```

### Outcome

I added a little dot to the screenshots to indicate where i tapped. You see the image is getting placed far off the expected locations

[image: Screenshot1][image: Screenshot2]

### Assumptions

I read a bit about the `Offset` object and i suspect the difference has something to do with the conversion to **.dp** which i need to feed the offset to the marker image **Modifier**.

It might also be related to coordinates being related to it's parent views or something, but since in my example theres nothing else in the UI but the image, i can't grasp this as a possible candidate.

Any help appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by replacing

```
modifier = Modifier.offset( offset.x.dp, offset.y.dp )
```

with

```
modifier = Modifier.offset(
     x= LocalDensity.current.run{offset.x.toInt().toDp()},
     y= LocalDensity.current.run{offset.y.toInt().toDp()} )
```

Turned out my mistake was that I ignored the properties of dp by just casting the pixel value to dp. Instead, I should call the local device density to correctly determine the amount of pixels for the transformation.